# Access rails model attributes through a has one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

My User has one Driver:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :driver, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

User attributes include, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_email and user_phone number.

I want to be able to access these User attributes when working with the driver class.

For example:

```
@drivers = Driver.where( :user_first_name => "David )
```

Obviously the above code won't work, since user_first_name is not a Driver attribute, but is there a way to do this without looping through each user record?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to Rails but hopefully this is helpful!

If you create a foreign key index to associate your model's tables within the database, then you should be able to access the data like so...

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@drivers = Driver.where( @user.user_first_name => "David" )
```

Also, not sure if it was a typo here, but you forgot to close the quotes with "David.